# Using Javascript and EJS why might the \ escape character turn one quote " into two quotes ""?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

**Environment:** Node.js, Express, EJS

**Question:** Why might the `\` escape character turn one quote `"` into two quotes `""`?

**Background:** In the following simplified example I'm sending an object (emailField) to an EJS file for rendering.  It doesn't throw an error but the output is unexpected and I'm not sure why I'm getting double "".

**The Express route:**

```
app.get('/my_form', function(req, res, next){

    emailField = {
        attributes: 'type=\"email\" minLength=\"5\" maxLength=\"50\" autofocus'

        \\ same output if I use single quote "
        \\ attributes: 'type="email" minLength="5" maxLength="50" autofocus'
    }

    res.render('my_form', emailField);
});
```

**From my_form EJS:**

```
<input <%= emailField.attributes %>>
```

**The output in Chrome:**

```
<input type=""email"" minlength=""5"" maxlength=""50"" autofocus>
```

Comment: Are you sure you need the `\\` in that example?

Comment: @Shiny Dang you are right.  When I use 1 quote " with or without the escape character I get double.  However when I use no quotes at all it adds 1 quote " in the final output.  Now I'm super confused.

Comment: You only need to escape double quotes if they're inside other double quotes. If they're inside single quotes, they don't need escaping, they're treated just like any other character.

Comment: Try to use <%- emailField.attributes %> instead of <%= emailField.attributes %>